# Perl create byte array and file stream

Tags: perl, cgi, arrays, bytearrayoutputstream

I need to be able to send a file stream and a byte array as a response to an HTTP POST for the testing of a product.  I am using CGI perl for the back end, but I am not very familiar with Perl yet, and I am not a developer, I am a Linux Admin.  Sending a string based on query strings was very easy, but I am stuck on these two requirements.  Below is the script that will return a page with Correct or Incorrect depending on the query string.  How can I add logic to return a filestream and byte array as well?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI ':standard';

print header();
print start_html();

my $query = new CGI;
my $value = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};


my $number = '12345';

if ( $value == $number ) {
print  "<h1>Correct Value</h1>\n";
} else {
print "<h1>Incorrect value, you said: $value</h1>\n";
}
print end_html();
```

Comment: is the other end JavaScript based?

Comment: No, right now they are actually hitting this script directly, mind you the client is not a browser, it is a device that makes raw HTTP commands. This script is just to test the device.  Initially it was html/perl CGI, but now they are just calling the perl script directly and passing a query string like POST /test.cgi?12345 HTTP/1.1 Host: myhost.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad to see new people dabbling in Perl from the sysadmin field.  This is precisely how I started.

First off, if you're going to use the CGI.pm module I would suggest you use it to your advantage throughout the script.  Where you've previously inputted `<h1>` you can use your CGI object to do this for you.  In the end, you'll end up with much cleaner, more manageable code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI ':standard';

print header();
print start_html();

my $value = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
my $number = '12345';

if ( $value == $number ) {
    h1("Correct Value");
} else {
    h1("Incorrect value, you said: $value");
}

print end_html();
```

Note that your comparison operator (`==`) will only work if this is a number.  To make it work with strings as well, use the `eq` operator.

A little clarification regarding what you mean regarding filestreams and byte arrays ... by file stream, do you mean that you want to print out a file to the client?  If so, this would be as easy as:

```
open(F,"/location/of/file");
while (<F>) {
    print $_;
}
close(F);
```

This opens a file handle linked to the specified file, read-only, prints the content line by line, then closes it.  Keep in mind that this will print out the file as-is, and will not look pretty in an HTML page.  If you change the Content-type header to "text/plain" this would probably be more within the lines of what you're looking for.  To do this, modify the call which prints the HTTP headers to:

```
 print header(-type => 'text/plain');
```

If you go this route, you'll want to remove your `start_html()` and `end_html()` calls as well.

As for the byte array, I guess I'll need a little bit more information about what is being printed, and how you want it formatted.

Comment: Nice post.  I just wanted to add that using CGI.pm's html-output functionality has largely been replaced by the simplicity of module's such as HTML::Template.  CGI.pm is mostly used for request handling, but not so much for output.  HTML::Template facilitates separating the output (view) from the code (ie, one step in the direction of MVC)

Comment: I just wanted an arbitrary byte array and file stream to be sent back to the client for testing purposes.. It doesn't matter what they contain, but should be relatively small for simplicity's sake.

Comment: I sent an email to the devs for clarification and it turns out the code I gave them was sufficient.  If anyone is able to decipher what they might have wanted and show me the code, that would be cool.  I am going to try to get better at Perl so next time I will be ready for the task.